# getting dropdownchecklist working with knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to get [dropdownchecklist](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) jquery plugin working with ko. I've wired up custom binding handler but dropdown won't populate with options. Please check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amitava82/wMH8J/11/

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you create dropdown **before** binding KnockoutJS. How does this dropdown work? It creates additional *divs* and *spans* which copy the content of *select* and create nice looking list. After that bindings are applied and they modify the select (as they should), but dropdown **is not** updated, because this library is kind of static, i.e. it copies the content of *select* only at the time of calling.

I've updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMH8J/12/) so you can see temporary fix. What I mean is that it works now, the binding is applied **before** creating dropdown. The only problem is that changing `options` field in `viewModel` won't affect the dropdown. What you probably need to do is to use [subscribe method](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables). You have to monitor changes to `options` field and if they occur you have to recreate the dropdown. That's an easy way at least.

Comment: I've generally found that creating Knockout binding wrappers for various jQuery libs works well for our project. They're usually fairly simple.

Comment: Thanks, your solution does solve the issue. I'd definitely like to know about the wrapper technique that @Svend mentioned. That would help me to understand how to work with different JQuery plugins with KO. I'll make the answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

@freakish answer will work for most static content, but for anything dynamic using templates, for example `if` or `foreach` bindings, or you need to support underlying data updates, such as more checkbox options "suddenly" becoming available, it will not work.

An example of [a really simple `$.button` binding](http://jsfiddle.net/stofte/CnCFz/) `apply` which can be used to wrap the more simple jQuery calls. It's a simple matter of adding more members to `controls` to make them available in bindings.

The case with jQuery Dropdown Check List is a bit tricky however, since you obviously want to use the built in `options` handler, but you need to run `$.dropdownchecklist` after the `options` handler has run, as it creates the DOM elements that jQuery depends on. [By wrapping the built in `options` handler](http://jsfiddle.net/stofte/jwjcZ/2/), we are always called in the correct context.

In my experience of usage (our project makes use of about 10-15 custom bindings), you'll average about 10-20 lines of actual JS. If you start ballooning into +100 lines, I find it's a good idea to refactor, and rethink. I hope this helps some :-) I've been using Knockout for a few months now at a major UI implementation project at work, I've really learned alot, and I'm amazed at this stuff.